# How to get selected row in C1flexgrid?

Tags: c#, c1flexgrid

I use ' SelectionMode : Row ' now

I already used MouseClickArgs, CheckBox and etc

Q : How to get selected and highlighted row?

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow :) Your question is very low quality and I do not think it is going to get accepted in its current state. Please check out [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a better question and revise your question to better meet those guidelines :)

Comment: @SuitBoyApps Thank you for your advice.